# postfixのsendmailコマンドでメール送信できない

Tags: postfix

192.168.100.XXXのローカル環境でメールサーバを構築しました。

GUI上ではメールの送受信は問題なくおこなえています。
・メールサーバマシン1台
・メールクライアントマシン1台

GUI上のメーラーでクライアントからサーバに送信すると、
サーバ側の/var/log/maillogに送信ログがはかれています。

しかし、コマンドライン上で、sendmail hoge@mailsvr.local
を実行してメール送信すると、サーバ側のメーラーにはメールが届きません。

しかも、クライアントマシン側の/var/log/maillogにログが
はかれてしまっています。

以下、クライアントマシン側にはかれてしまったログの内容

```
Dec1617:42:45 mailcli-01 postfix/pickup[7294]: 1BC409F50D: uid=502 from=<cliuser01>
Dec16 17:42:45 mailcli-01 postfix/cleanup[7884]: 1BC409F50D: message-id=<20151216084245.1BC409F50D@mailcli-01.local>
Dec 16 17:42:45 mailcli-01 postfix/qmgr[7295]: 1BC409F50D: from=<cliuser01@mailcli-01.local>, size=335, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 17:42:45 mailcli-01 postfix/smtp[7871]: 1BC409F50D: to=<svruser01@mailsvr-01.local>, relay=none, delay=1.6, delays=1.6/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=mailsvr-01.local type=MX: Host not found, try again) ? bird 40
```

考えられる理由を、ご教授いただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: DNSに登録されているMxレコード("@mailsvr.local"宛てのメールに対処するサーバのIPアドレスを定義したデータ）は、どうなっていますか？　メールサーバマシンに届かないのは、MXレコードが無いか、内容に不備があるからではないでしょうか。

Comment: クライアントマシン側にMXレコードがあるかということでしょうか。

すいません、MXレコードがありませんでした。この環境ではMXレコードなしで、/etc/hostsのみの設定で送信はできないのでしょうか？

無知なのですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `status=bounced (unknown user: "svruser01")`って言っていますよ。hogeじゃなくて実際にやったことを書いてください。ちなみにMXは不要です。

Comment: @Noguchiさん
すいません、実際にクライアントマシン側で/va/log/maillogにはかれたログを下記します。少しいじってしまったので、先ほどと内容は少し違っておりますが、現象はかわらず、GUI上のメールソフト上ではメールの送受信はおこなえておりますが、コマンドライン上での送信ができず、本来メールサーバ側の/var/log/maillogにはかれるべきログがクライアント側ではかれてしまっております。次のコメントでクライアント側ではかれているログです。

Comment: Dec1617:42:45 mailcli-01 postfix/pickup[7294]: 1BC409F50D: uid=502 from=<cliuser01>
Dec16 17:42:45 mailcli-01 postfix/cleanup[7884]: 1BC409F50D: message-id=<20151216084245.1BC409F50D@mailcli-01.local>
Dec 16 17:42:45 mailcli-01 postfix/qmgr[7295]: 1BC409F50D: from=<cliuser01@mailcli-01.local>, size=335, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 17:42:45 mailcli-01 postfix/smtp[7871]: 1BC409F50D: to=<svruser01@mailsvr-01.local>, relay=none, delay=1.6, delays=1.6/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=mailsvr-01.local type=MX: Host not found, try again)

Comment: DNSサーバは稼働させていますか？　稼働させていないのなら、dnsmasq(http://int128.hatenablog.com/entry/20120226/1330247800)のようなDNSサーバを導入してください。 dnsmasqにMxレコードを設定する方法は、http://dev.tapweb.co.jp/2009/09/77に解説があります。　hostsファイルにMxレコードの情報を持たせることは出来ません。

Comment: @Fumu7 さん
DNSサーバを稼働させてないので、dnsmasqを導入してみます。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

別解として回答します。

SMTPリレーが失敗してますが MUA からの SMTP 送信は成功してますので、もしも、SMTPリレーが必ずしも必要なく、コマンドラインからメール送信できれば良い、という事であれば、mailx コマンドでSTMP送信すればいいと思います。

設定ファイルにSMTPサーバー、必用であれば認証等を記述 (項目は man mailx で確認してください)

```
$ vi ~/.mailrc
set smtp=smtp://mailsvr-01.local:25
set smtp-auth=login
set smtp-auth-user=xxxx
set smtp-auth-password=xxxxx
```

送信

```
$ mail -s "Mail Test" svruser01@mailsvr-01.local < mail.txt
```

Comment: @take88さん
ありがとうございます。mailxはMUAでの送信ということなんですね。
理解が広がりました。

Answer (score 1):

クライアント(mailcli-01)のコマンドラインから sendmail コマンドでメールを送る場合、mailcli-01 の postfix の設定が必要です。
デフォルトの設定では DNS の MXレコードを調べて配送先メールサーバーを決めるようになっていると思います。

現状では「mailsvr-01.local」ドメインの MXレコードが見つからないので、status=deferred (一時的なエラー)となり、メールを配送できず、mailcli-01 のメールキューに溜まります。

「mailsvr-01.local」ドメインの DNSサーバーが必要ですが、そういう大掛かりなものではなく、単純に上位メールサーバー(SMTPサーバー)に送るのであれば、relayhost または transport_maps の設定で可能と思います。

Comment: @Taichiさん
ありがとうございます。
relayhostの設定を見直したらうまくいきました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

Postfix は、デフォルトでは自身で宛先ドメインの MX を DNS で検索しようとするので、該当する MX RR が索けない場合は提示されているログのように `MX: Host not found` になり一時エラー、最終的にはバウンスします。

メールクライアントマシンの Postfix のメール配送において、自身で MX の解決はせず、すべてのメール配送をメールサーバーマシンに依頼したいということであれば、`main.cf` にでも `relayhost = [メールサーバーのホスト名]` あるいは `relayhost = [メールサーバーのIPアドレス]` とすればいいです。これにより、自ホスト宛でないメールはすべてメールサーバーに配送されるようになります。

もちろん、メールサーバーの Postfix では、mailsvr-01.local ドメイン宛のメールをリレーあるいはローカル配送するようにする、もしくはメールクライアントホストからのメールリレーを許可する必要があります。

Comment: @fumiyasさん

ありがとうございます。
relayhostの設定を見直してうまくいきました。